# Using webpack-i18n-plugin with CommonsChunkPlugin

Tags: webpack, webpack-2

The requirement is to create app bundle per each language and also split vendor modules. The following webpack.config.js

```
// webpack.config.js
var webpack = require('webpack')
var path = require('path')
var I18nPlugin = require("i18n-webpack-plugin")

var locales = {
    "en": require("./m1/js/en.json"),
    "ja": require("./m1/js/ja.json")
}

module.exports = Object.keys(locales).map(function (locale) {
    return {
        name: locale,
        entry: "./m1/js/main.js",
        output: {
            filename: 'app-' + locale + '.js',
            path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'm1/js/build')
        },
        plugins: [
            new I18nPlugin(
                locales[locale],
                {
                    functionName: '_t',
                }
            ),
            new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
                name: 'vendor',
                minChunks: function (module) {
                    return module.context && module.context.indexOf('node_modules') !== -1;
                }
            })
        ]
    }
})
```

throws following errors:

```
ERROR in chunk vendor [entry]
app-en.js
Conflict: Multiple assets emit to the same filename app-en.js

ERROR in chunk vendor [entry]
app-ja.js
Conflict: Multiple assets emit to the same filename app-ja.js
```

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I changed my web.config.js like below:

```
...
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name: 'vendor',
            filename: 'vendor.js',
            minChunks: function (module) {
                return module.context && module.context.indexOf('node_modules') !== -1;
            }
        })
...
```

and it worked. I'm just not sure whether it is efficient or correct. My concern is map function. Is it writing to vendor.js for each locale?